# Is it allowed to have instance variables in Spring Services?

Tags: java, spring, service

I have a spring service that provides configuration data. When the service is invoked by the GUI, it loads the configuration data from the database. It turns out that this happens quite often during the rendering of a single request. I want to optimize this by caching the configuration data. However, I am not sure if this is a good programming style or if it is "allowed" to have an instance variable in a service.

Here is some example code of what I am thinking of doing:

```
@Serivce("MyConfigService")
public class MyConfigServiceImpl implements MyConfigService {

    private Config cachedConfig;

    @Override
    public Config loadConfig() {
        if (cachedConfig != null) {
            // load config
            cachedConfig = loadedConfig;
        }
        return cachedConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public saveConfig(Config config) {
        cachedConfig = null;
        // save the configuration
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure you can to this, but I would suggest to make your Service an Initializing bean. This way Spring automatically calls special callbacks when initializing your bean and you can be sure that initialization is done before any other service can start using your bean: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-initializingbean-and-disposablebean-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are instance variables allowed in Spring service layer classes? Sure.

Is it a good idea to use one to save a reference to the `Config` object here?

Maybe, maybe not.

You're not showing how `Config` normally gets loaded...  Does the same `Config` instance get returned to all users? i.e. - When User1 calls `saveConfig` then User2 calls `loadConfig` User2 gets the `Config` object User1 saved.

If so, you should be able to cache the value with no problems.

Also, instead of implementing it yourself, you could use Spring's [annotation-based caching](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

Comment: Yes, Config is a global application wide configuration object that only exists once and is not user dependent.

Answer (score 5):

Having a instance variable (not managed by spring) introduces the possibility of the service becoming thread unsafe. So I try to avoid them, or make sure they are thread safe.

You may want to look at `@configurable` and `@postconstuct` annotations to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables is what Spring IoC container is all about; what is dubious in your design is that you have your own lazy-loading logic in `loadConfig`—that's the concern you must leave to Spring via `lazy-init=true` (or similar, I don't remember exactly). The design will also probably involve lookup methods and posibly request-scoped beans.